# update multiple columns with case/if statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Thank you in advance:

I have a table1:

```
id       ||   batches  || IC_chips

DRG001   ||   JHL001   || layer1
DRG001   ||   JHL001   || layer2
DRG001   ||   JHL001   || layer3
DRG001   ||   JHL001   || layer4
DRG001   ||   JHL001   || layer5
DRG001   ||   JHL001   || layer6
DRG001   ||   JHL002   || layer7
DRG001   ||   JHL002   || layer8
DRG001   ||   JHL002   || layer9
DRG001   ||   JHL002   || layer10
POQ001   ||   ADG001   || layer1
POQ001   ||   ADG001   || layer2
POQ001   ||   ADG001   || layer3
POQ001   ||   ADG001   || layer4
POQ001   ||   ADG001   || layer5
POQ001   ||   ADG001   || layer6
```

the output table is :

```
ID     ||   print_batch_1   ||  Print_batch_2  ||  Count_print_batch_1  || Count_print_batch_2  ||  Batch_count
DRG001 ||   JHL001          ||  JHL002         ||  06                   || 04                    ||  02
POQ001 ||   ADG001          ||  Null           ||  06                   || Null                  ||  01
```

i tried it with an update statement but i am facing an issue when their are more than one Print batches.

this is the code i tried with :

```
update tab
set Count_name=b.Count_name
,batch_count=b.batch_count
from
table1 tab
inner join
(
select Name, count(batches) as Count_name, count(distinct batches) as 
batch_count
from table1
group by batches) b
on tab.batches=b.batches
```

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: i am using MSSQL 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this -

```
update tab B
set Count_name = a.batches, batch_count = batch_cnt
from    (
            select  batches, count(*) batch_cnt
            from    table1 A
            where   a.batches = b.batches
        )
where
    exists (
                select  1
                from    table1 A
                where   a.batches = b.batches
            )
```

Comment: i am getting this error Amey: **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.**

Comment: This code is for oracle SQL and don't know structure of table 'tab'. Also please try assigning alias to sub-query used in 'from' clause.